# The right approach to listen to GCM notifications

Tags: android, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to build a GCM notification listener, which will basically use the notification to flag the user that some operation should be made (which involve communicating with my remote App-Server).
I assumed that I should create a UI-less application running on the device's startup and listen to the GCM notifications and issue the internal android notification. When the user opens the notification an activity will be opened which will do the rest of the job with the remote App-Server.
Looking at notification examples it seems to me that I may be missing some basic understanding since all te examples which I had found use a UI application to manipulate the notifications.
What do I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common use case for handling of GCM messages in Android apps is as follows :

1. Your app registers to GCM upon startup and sends the registration ID to your server.
2. Your server sends a GCM message to your app.
3. You app receives the message in a broadcast receiver, which usually starts an intent service.
4. The intent service usually displays a notification to the user.
5. The user taps the notification, which starts an activity of the app.

You can see this use case implemented in the [official GCM demo](https://code.google.com/p/gcm/source/browse/gcm-client/GcmClient/src/main/java/com/google/android/gcm/demo/app/) and in many other examples.

The fact that the app you wish to develop has no UI doesn't prevent you from implementing the exact same use case.

Comment: Thanks Eran for your prompt reply. What I’m not sure about is whether there should be 2 applications – one responsible for notifications (- receiving the gcm one and issuing the android one) and another application which will be launched when the user opens the android notification and be responsible for the business logic, or all this should be done in one application. In the example it is only one application, but is it the right approach given the fact that the application stays resident in memory all along? (Sorry if my assumptions regarding android are wrong, I’m a newbie in this area).

Comment: @user3822119 I don't think you need two apps. The application doesn't have to stay resident in memory all along in order to receive GCM messages. That's the point of GCM, to make it possible to wake an app that's not running at all. If you write an app that stays resident in memory all the time, you don't need GCM messages to wake it.

Comment: OK, so how do I avoid leaving my app in memory? Do I need to do something exlicitly?

Comment: Finally I managed to make it working. Thanks! (Sorry I can't up-vote due to low reputation yet).